# Fill adjacent column rows if null

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a query question.  I am working with a set of data similar to the table below:

```
╔══════╦═══════════╗
║ Col1 ║   Col2    ║
╠══════╬═══════════╣
║    1 ║ NULL      ║
║    2 ║ NULL      ║
║    3 ║ NULL      ║
║    4 ║ AAAAAAAAA ║
║    5 ║ NULL      ║
╚══════╩═══════════╝
```

I need to find a way to populate all `NULL` values in `Col2` with the non-NULL `Col2` value.  So the results of the query should populate all 5 rows with `AAAAAAAAA`, as long as there is at least 1 non-NULL value.

EDIT: it doesn't have to be `AAAAAAAAA` to populate the remaining rows really. It can be anything, as long as there is some way to identify that there is at least 1 non-null value in the set.

Comment: What is expected if two of the rows have different non-NULL values for `col2`? E.g., what would you expect if `col2` would be `BBBBBBB` in the first row?

Comment: Did you mean "populate all NULL values in 'col2' with the non-NULL 'col1' value." ?

Comment: @StefanWinkler as long as there is at least 1 non null then there needs to be some identifier that there was a non-null in the set.  So if there was a BBBBBBBB and an AAAAAA, then it would still pass the test.  It doesn't really matter what the values are changed to- it might be even better to just change everything to a distinct value if it passes the test, such as "xyz".  that works too.

Comment: @ConradFrix SQL server, yes the syntax may differ slightly but the logic is similar.

Comment: @TarikZouine no.  there needs to be some way to identify that there is a non-null in column 2.

Comment: what if there are several different non null values in Col2 ? which one should be picked up to replace the null values ?

Comment: @TarikZouine it can be anything.  A unique value might be even better, such as 'XYZ' just to mark it as passing the logical test.

Comment: I removed the MySQL tag based on the comment that this is for SQL Server (my apologies to the answers who used MySQL syntax, don't downvote them).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need to:

1. Get a not null value in `col2` from your table, and
2. Set all null values in `col2` to the value obtanied in the previous step

If that is the case, then I think this might help you:

```
-- I am assuming that there's only one not-null value in col2
set @value = (select col2 from yourTable where col2 is not null limit 1);
update yourTable
    set col2 = @value
    where col2 is null;
```

Answer (score 0):

The following should work in either MySQL or SQL Server:

```
update table t
    set col2 = (select x from (select max(col2) as x from table t where col2 is not null) t)
    where col2 is null;
```

Comment: I like the max idea in the sub query.. but i don't need to update the table permanently with the SET.  I was thinking something along the lines of a case statement.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood your need but ...

```
UPDATE t
SET col2 = (
        SELECT col2
        FROM t
        WHERE col2 IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
        )
WHERE col2 IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select table1.col1, COALESCE(table1.col2, 'xyz') 
  from table as table1
```

Comment: the coalesce will just change the non-nulls to 'xyz', for ALL of them, no matter what.  I only want the values to change if there is a non-null among them.  Many instances are only comprised of NULLS, as opposed to my example above where there are 4 nulls and a 'AAAAAAAAA' value.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you would just write what you want in the question.  And what you makes not sense to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a case statement and don't need the table permanently altered (presumably you just want output from it altered), just do this:

```
SELECT
   col1,
   col2 = case
       WHEN exists(select col2 from table where col2 is not null) then 'dummyVal'
        else col2 end
FROM table
```

If you need the dummy value to be some actual value from the table though, why not just use max or min functions, both of which ignore nulls.

```
SELECT
    col1,
    col2 = max(col2)
FROM table
```